# Writing a block within a loop

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I need some advise on the following code:

```
for ( ...; ++i )
{
   int count = i;

   [self fetchFromServer completion:^(BOOL success) {
         // access the value of count here
   });
}
```

Because it takes awhile before the block is complete. So when I access "count", will the value be what I expected?

Thanks!

Comment: When you tried it, what happened? I mean you did try it, didn't you, which is simple enough? When you read up on how blocks work, what did you find? This is really the very first thing that Apple's documentation tells you.

Comment: Because it happened so fast and the result always seems correct that I wasn't sure about it.

Comment: So what does Apple's documentation say? Did you read it? That would be the very first step.

Comment: i read through "Working With Block" and there isn't an example with a outer for-loop

Comment: [Straight from the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW1): _Stack (non-static) variables local to the enclosing lexical scope are captured as const variables.
Their values are taken at the point of the block expression within the program. In nested blocks, the value is captured from the nearest enclosing scope._

Comment: that explains why it works. thanks Alladinian